# JavaScript errors does not show in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, typeerror, devtools, javascript-debugger

I'm developing a js game and I debug it using Chrome DevTools.

Recently I noticed that some errors are not reported to the console even though they freeze the code execution.

The only way I can debug those errors is running row by row until I see the error while hovering over the problematic variable. (for ex. trying to read a property of an 'undefined' variable (TypeError))

If it matters I use 'use strict' as well.

Update: I noticed that if I check 'Pause on caught exceptions' the code will stop on the error. What can cause such error to be caught without using a trycatch around it?

Thank you

Comment: could you provide an example of error raising code that is not being reported?

Comment: the last one was for using 'this.prop' inside a closure, the error msg was "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined")

Comment: are you by any chance using angular?

Comment: This project uses only jquery

Comment: ok, because there was a know issue with angular and zone.js that had this due to a piece of code cathing a thrown error and not logging it, so it could be something similar in your code or framework

Comment: Update: I noticed that if I check 'Pause on caught exceptions' the code will stop on the error. What can cause such error to be caught without using a trycatch around it?

Comment: Ok so it is that then. Basically what is happening is the blackbox code you are using must have a scenario somewhere where something will throw an error or even a try catch, but the blackbox code catches it in an empty catch {} statement leaving no trace, until you select pause